# Android - Determine App Launches and Total Time as Top Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am working on a solution or code that can be embedded inside of an Android APK to track how many times the app has been launched and how long the app has ran for.  I know one way to do this is using the ActivityLifecycleMethods in API 14 and in lower versions of Android having code placed in all Activity Lifecycle events or by providing a base Activity class.

1) Is there a way to hook the ActivityLifecycleMethods without the developer having to make any changes to their code outside of dropping additional code into their App?

I believe this answer is no because even with an Enum Singleton it is not loaded until it is referenced.  Also the Enum Singleton will go away once the activity is changed since a different class loader is used when activities change.

If I wanted to keep the Enum Singleton around would it be possible to store a reference to the applicationContext and thus it wouldn't be removed when the Activity changes?  Is that what google means by 
"There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton." on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

2) I am not a fan of this solution for older API versions. It seems very likely developers could forget to modify their Activity Lifecycle methods or forget to inherit from the created BaseActivity.  Are there any other unique solutions for these older platforms?  Is there any other approaches that can be done to determine when an activity isn't running?  Could any of the following work:

a) User a class loader to ensure the base activity with the proper metrics are always used
b) Implement some type of heart beat.  Will a timer stop working if the app is paused or killed?  Is there some other way?  Could the ActivityManager be used?

Answer (score 0):

You have many Analytic Agents like Flurry to do that.
When ever you want to track an event, you will add it to flurry and inturn it syncs with server after specific time.

You may use the same logic.

Better create a library file with following features:

1. Start Application
2. End Application and report time to db.
3. Track a specific event count and update to db.
4. Sync the data to server you like to.

Call appropriate events from your app.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to do this with the developer having to write and maintain as little code as possible. With the developer calling start app and end app it is very easy for developers to add new entry and exit points and miss adding the corresponding calls to the library. It just feels like a better developer experience to provide less code. I am just not sure if there is a feasible option.